# Rewrite multi-thread wait using async/await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0

We have a webservice function that runs a list of tasks in the background.  When all tasks are complete, it returns.  I've revisited the function for C# 5.  I've managed to get the following snippet working:

```
var result = new List<int>();
var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

foreach (var row in rowlist)
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(row)));
foreach (var task in tasks)
    result.Add(task.Result);
```

The `task.Result` waits for the individual task to be done.  I've tested this by adding a three second delay to the `DoWork` method and verifying that it finishes in less than 5 seconds, for a list of 10 tasks.

Now I've tried to rewrite the function using the new `async / await` syntax.  But I can't seem to get it to work.  If it compiles, it runs synchronously, as verified by adding a wait.

Any ideas on how you can rewrite the above snippet using `async / await` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
var tasks = rowlist.Select(row => Task.Run(() => DoWork(row)));

var results = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).ToList();
```

Basically, you still create the tasks the way you were previously (without using `await`), as you want them to all start immediately.  You can then wait for all of them to complete asynchronously (via `await Task.WhenAll`), then pull out the results at once (since you know they're all done).

Comment: This runs async.  But it results in an `System.AggregateException`, inner exception `{"The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."}`  Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps more importantly: why does this run synchronously if you omit the line with `await` ?

Comment: @Andomar Call `ToList` after `Select` when creating the tasks.  That should fix the error.  Currently when enumerating `tasks` several times it would be trying to create the new tasks twice, which would be bad.

Comment: @Andomar It runs synchronously because `Result` will block until the task is finished if the task isn't already done.  `await` does a whole bunch of magic to make the rest of the method run synchronously.  It will end the method call as soon as it hits the `await`.  When `WhenAll` completes (i.e., when all of the other tasks are done) it will cause a continuation to fire (`await` creates and attaches that continuation); that continuation will have the remainder of the method (i.e. the line that grabs the results).

Comment: You can simplify this slightly: `var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: @Servy: Your fix for the `AggregateException` works.  It's surprising that `Tasks.Run()` is synchronous unless the function contains an `await`!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Andomar `Task.Run` is **not** synchronous.  It is the `task.Result` that was doing the blocking.

Comment: Since the code has been improved to just returning the results of `WhenAll` it is no longer iterating `tasks` more than once, so the `ToList` on the first line is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Reed Copsey, Servy and Stephen Cleary's answer and comments I've progressed to this solution:

```
var results = rowlist
    .Select(row => Task.Run(() => DoWork(row)))
    .ToList()
    .Select(t => t.Result);
```

The second `Select` will wait on the tasks to finish.  I've added a `ToList()` in between to prevent streaming, but it seems to work without that.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the code you started out with.  You need the `await` in there...

Comment: @Servy: Now I'm confused: wasn't it you who commented above that `task.Result` can block too?  The code does work by the way: 10 tasks in 4 seconds, where each task has a sleep for 3 seconds.

Comment: The whole point of using async/await is that the entire method (that this code sits in) won't block.  You could call the methods from, for example, an event in a GUI application and not have it block the UI thread (while still running all of the needed code in the UI thread).  Using `await` the method doesn't actually return the results, it returns a task that will inform you when those results were computed (and possibly what those results were).

Comment: @Servy: Would `await` not block a GUI thread?  I see your point though, but here the requirement is just to parallelize tasks in a readable way.  It's certainly better than the old way which used  a list of `ManualResetEvent` objects.

Comment: No, if you used `await` you wouldn't block a UI thread.  That's what's so great about it. You can write code that looks synchronous, just like you would think about it, but it will do a whole bunch of magic that transforms it into a continuation/callback model which prevents the thread from being blocked.  As for the requirement, the question specifically asks to rewrite the code to use async/await, so excluding it is not meeting the [your] requirements.